# The tagging element is not coming in JSON Output

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I want the order list element come as like the input XML file in the output JSON file. I tried using XSLT, but it's not working

My input XML file is:

```
<description>
  <p>This medicine is classified as a GLP-1 receptor agonist.</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Use this medicine once a week</li>
  </ol>
</description>
```

The XSL Which I use is:

```
<xsl:template match="description">
    description: 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ol">
    <ol><xsl:apply-templates/></ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
    <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Output XML which I got is:

```
description: 'This medicine is classified as a b : "GLP-1 receptor agonist."'
Use this medicine once a week
```

I expect output JSON as:

```
description: 'This medicine is classified as a b : "GLP-1 receptor agonist."'
    <ol><li>Use this medicine once a week</li></ol>
```

Is this possible in XML to JSON conversion?
Please check and provide me the correct XSLT code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your input xml and output is not matching. How the text changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed your XSLT to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

  <xsl:template match="description">
    description: 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ol">
    <ol><xsl:apply-templates/></ol>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li">
    <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick - the difference between both of you outputs lies in the `method` attribute of the `<xsl:output ...>` element at the beginning.

If you use

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="text" />
```

you will get

```
description: 
This medicine is classified as a GLP-1 receptor agonist.Use this medicine once a weekctbankix@ctbankix:~/Do
```

and if you use

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
```

you will get

```
description: 
    This medicine is classified as a GLP-1 receptor agonist.<ol>
  <li>Use this medicine once a week</li>
</ol>
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only `match` elements or node which will be processed and for your requirement you just need to do the `copy-of` node `ol` as follows,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

  <xsl:template match="description">
    description: 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="ol">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```